# Loading multiple file formats together in snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have 2 types of file format 1. Xml and 2. Json.  How can we load 2 types of files together to snowpipe?

Comment: You can't load two different file formats on the same variant column on the same table using the same pipe. You can create two different pipes and two tables and load the files based on a pattern to their respective table.  What are you trying to achieve using a single pipe?

Comment: @Sergiu can you post this as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can't load two different file formats on the same variant column on the same table using the same pipe.

You can create two different pipes and two tables and load the files based on a pattern to their respective table.

What are you trying to achieve using a single pipe?